# Mostrar campo y su contenido de base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Que tal!

Tengo un detalle al momento de mostrar una consulta

este es mi codigo en donde consulto y muestro el resultado:

```
$consulta_A = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI'AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' ORDER BY mes DESC") or die("Error en consulta Agenda".mysqli_error($con));

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_A)) {
                $documento = $row["documento"];                
                 $mes = $row["mes"];
                 $ruta = $row["ruta"];
                 $departamento = $row["departamento"];
                  ?>                    
                <ul><?php echo $mes; ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo "plataforma/".$ruta.$documento; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $departamento; ?></a></li> 
                </ul>
```

El problema es que en el resultado que obtengo el mes se repite tantas veces como exista en la base de datos:

> Septiembre
>
> - JURIDICO
>
> Octubre
>
> - JURIDICO
>
> Octubre
>
> - TRANSPARENCIA
>
> Mayo
>
> - JURIDICO
>
> Mayo
>
> - TRANSPARENCIA

y yo necesito mostrar solo el nombre del mes y todos los documentos dentro de ese mes, de esta manera:

> Septiembre
>
> - JURIDICO
>
> Octubre
>
> - JURIDICO
> - TRANSPARENCIA
>
> Mayo
>
> - JURIDICO
> - TRANSPARENCIA

Espero y puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1):

Bueno yo lo haría así, aunque debe haber una forma más simple:

```
$consulta_A = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI'AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' ORDER BY mes DESC") or die("Error en consulta Agenda".mysqli_error($con));
                $data = array();

              while ($row   = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_A)) {
                  $documento    = $row["documento"];
                  $mes          = $row["mes"];
                  $ruta         = $row["ruta"];
                  $departamento = $row["departamento"];

                  if(array_key_exists($mes,$data)){
                    array_push($data[$mes], array("mes"=>$mes,"ruta"=>"ruta","departamento"=>"departamento"));
                  }else{
                    $data[$mes] = array(
                        array("mes"=>$mes,"ruta"=>"ruta","departamento"=>"departamento")
                    );
                  };
                };//end while

                foreach($data as $key => $value){
                    echo "<ul><li>".$key."<ul>";

                    foreach($value as $item){
                        echo '<li><a href="plataforma/'.$item["ruta"].$item["documento"].'" target="_blank">'.$item["departamento"].'</a></li>';
                    };

                    echo "</ul></li></ul>";
                };
```

Puedes ver una muestra funcionando aqui: [MUESTRA](https://ideone.com/5i6ZRd)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías implementar una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT mes, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_',documento, departamento, ruta) ORDER BY mes SEPARATOR '|') datos_mes
       FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI' AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' 
       GROUP BY mes 
       ORDER BY mes DESC
```

Que te traerá los datos agrupados por mes, más o menos así:

```
Mes        datos_mes
Octubre    JURIDICO_dpto juridico_ruta juridico|TRANSPARENCIA_dpto..._ruta...
```

Luego puedes hacer un doble `explode`, primero sobre `|` para dividir los elementos, en el caso del ejemplo este explode dividiría primero así:

```
JURIDICO_dpto juridico_ruta juridico
```

Y...

```
TRANSPARENCIA_dpto..._ruta...
```

Luego haces otro `explode` sobre `_` para obtener cada elemento, así más o menos:

```
JURIDICO
    dpto juridico
    ruta juridico

TRANSPARENCIA
    dpto...
    ruta...
```

En la columna de afuera iría el mes.

He aquí el código. No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar.

```
$strSQL="SELECT mes, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_',documento, departamento, ruta) ORDER BY mes SEPARATOR '|') datos_mes
         FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI' AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' 
         GROUP BY mes 
         ORDER BY mes DESC";
$consulta_A = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL) or die("Error en consulta Agenda".mysqli_error($con));
$strHTML='';
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_A)) {
                    $strHTML .= '<ul>'.$row['mes'].'</ul>';
                    $arrDatos=explode('|',$row["datos_mes"]);
                    foreach ($arrDatos as $v){
                      $arrDetalle=explode('_',$v);
                      $documento=$arrDetalle[0];
                      $departamento=$arrDetalle[1];
                      $ruta=$arrDetalle[2];
                      $strHTML .= '<li><a href="plataforma/'.$ruta.$documento.'" target="_blank">'.$departamento.'</a></li>';                     
                    }
$strHTML .='</ul>';
echo $strHTML;
```